# Azure OpenAI Service REST API

Tags: rest, azure-openai, azure-ai-search

Is there any way to see what this API is doing when it creates an answer using an underlying Azure AI Search Index?

I get back the JSON response which contains chunks and the answer. But its hard to debug when it returns absolutely no chunks for some reason. Any possible troubleshooting steps I can take with this? I've gotten it not to do it be not having an array of messages (only one question "role:user"). But can't see what's happening with I pass it an array of messages and it returns nothing. Thanks for any help!

Comment: please share the thing u tried in the above question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Wesley Switzer Edit the question to include [desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help others answer the question.